# Which classification model do you suggest for predicting a credit score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I have a data set that contains information about whether medium-budget companies can get loans. There are data on the data set that approximately 38,000 different companies will receive loans. And based on this data, I'm trying to estimate each company's credit score. What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have credit scores? Without labeled data I think you might consider reformulating the problem.

If you do, then you can implement any number of regression algorithms from OLS all the way up to an ANN. Rather than look for the "one true" algorithm, many projects implement TPOT or grid search as part of model selection.